Why is my answer to this probability problem wrong?
Problem: What is the probability that in a room of $n$ people, at least two people share the same birthday? Discount the possibility of leap years for convenience.
I modeled this as follows -
Pick a pair to have the same birthday: $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ways
Give this pair a birthday: $365$ ways
Give the rest of the $n-2$ people birthdays: $365^{n-2}$
So the desired probability is $\frac{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\times{365\times{365^{n-2}}}}{365^n}$
But this doesn't yield the right answer.


Also, I have an even sillier yet perplexing follow-up:
Here's how I approached the probability of all individuals having distinct birthdays?
None of the pairs should have the same birthday. So the desired probability is $\frac{364}{365}^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ because the probability of any pair not having the same birthday is $\frac{1}{365}$.
This is clearly wrong because in the case of $n=3$, the correct answer is $\frac{365\cdot{364\cdot(363)}}{365^3}$, and my answer yields $\frac{364^3}{365^3}$. But I can't escape my reasoning.

You are overcounting the cases in which more than $2$ people share a birthday (you might have $3$ or more with the same day, or you might have two different dates with multiple births.)

The problem doesn't say anything about probability.

I have edited the problem to make it a probability question. Thanks for that correction. I care more about understanding why my probability is wrong.

The question (I assume) is about being born on the same day and not on the same year and the same day. So, your estimates  about pairs is incorrect. To see it consider a large number of people in the room, say $n = 1000$ ... clearly the number of pairs can not be larger than $365*354$, right?

I'm sorry. I still don't understand. The number of pairs of people would be 1001000/2. The number of ways in which two people can have different birthdays is 365 * 364. I don't see the discrepancy here.

Also, I have another question in the same vein:
Say there are three people at the party. Call event $A=$ person #1 and #2 have different birthdays, and event $B=$ person #2 and person #3 have different birthdays. Are events $A, B$ independent?

Got it! The probability of any pair not having the same birthday is $\frac{364}{365}$. And it's true that there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ pairs. Let's number these pairs 1 to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Then,
$P($all distinct birthdays$)=P($pair 1 distinct AND pair 2 distinct AND ... AND pair $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ distinct$)$. But,
$P($pair 1 distinct AND pair 2 distinct AND ... AND pair $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ distinct$) \neq \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} P($pair $i$ distinct$) = (\frac{364}{365})^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$
This is because these events are not independent. And this is very easy to prove.
